# Clustering of Features

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have multiview video dataset and I have extracted the features by using IDT (Improved Dense Trajectory Method). Dictionary of features is created using Vl_fisher method. Now, each row corresponds to a video and each column corresponds to a feature associated with each video. I want to apply clustering method to cluster the features but when I apply kmeans, spectral clustering I get the index of videos(rows) corresponding to each cluster but instead I want to know which feature corresponds to which cluster? Can anybody suggest any method. I am using Matlab for my work.

Comment: What do you mean by which feature corresponds to which cluster? Points are assigned to clusters not features.

Comment: Suppose I have 200x200 feature matrix, so when I apply spectral clustering with k = 10, I get which row belongs to which cluster but I want to know which specific cell value (means each row and column value that is feature) belongs to which cluster.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want the cluster centroid locations: [idx,C] = kmeans(___) returns the k cluster centroid locations in the k-by-p matrix C. That's the second output argument from kmeans.

Comment: Actually after applying kmeans I get the index which shows the row of the matrix and the value which shows cluster number but I don't want the cluster number, I want to know the specific feature (row and column number) which should be placed together